# Rerdirection to another site from my application

Tags: javascript, java

i am creating an application.i want to redirect from my application to another site.I am using username as session variable.But when it call back to my application then i dont getting session variable.I got the session variable as null.
I am using window.location.assign("sitename")

I have an application with my own username and password...after i login redirect to another site that site providing a login page.we enter the username and password of that site..then there is some processing is going on .then i got the result.but when return back i got the session null session.setAttribute("username", username);
 session.setAttribute("password", password);

Comment: your post is unclear

Comment: How do you store your session variable ? What have you tried ? Insert a sample of code, please

Comment: you want to make login in other website when you login with your website using same username and password?

Comment: I have an application with my own username and password...after i login redirect to another site that site providing a login page.we enter the username and password of that site..then there is some processing is going on .then i got the result.but when return back i got the session null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer
We can use local storage concept.So that we can store the username and password in the browse itself when we redirect to another site.In the browser inspect -> Resources - >Local storage. In local storage we hava ea url and it should be the same in the browser.
//to set the username
 localStorage.setItem("username", "Smith");
//to Retrieve the username`localStorage.getItem("lastname");`

Thank you